# Can $dF_p:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$ be surjective?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $N$ a smooth manifold with boundary, $F:M\to N$ a smooth map, if $F(p)\in \partial N$, can $dF_p:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$ be surjective?

Comment: $M$ is a manifold without a boundary ?

Comment: @HKLee Sure. Smooth manifold always means smooth manifold without boundary, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If $F(p)\in \partial N$, then  $dF_p:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$ is not surjective;
 if $dF_p:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$  is surjective, then  $F(p)\notin \partial N$.